# (MacOS) Is there a standard location for user-specific LaunchDaemons to write a .pid file to?

Tags: macos, nginx, pid, launchd, fhs

For ...reasons outside my control... I need to setup a `launchd` task to run a `nginx` service while a specific user is logged in.

In general this has been mostly straightforward, except for the fact that `/var/run` is not writable from a standard user account.  I also cannot just one-time create a `/var/run/nginx` folder with that user granted permissions to write to, as on restart the entire `/var/run` contents are wiped.

I couldn't seem to find any 'best practices' for other locations.  And I also couldnt find a way for the `launchd` plist to tell it to create a writable file for the daemon (ie, something like the `StandardOutPath` but for a .pid file)

Help!

Comment: Often `/var/tmp` is used by daemons with insufficient privileges.